# The chatroom is too cold

Tags: support, status-completed, chat

Well, I'm not complaining, [a frozen chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32641458#32641458) means the site really isn't running into any big issues, right? No spam, bad posts, users, etc. needed to be removed quickly by a request there, but it appears that no one (who isn't from my understanding a room owner) can't post any messages, may I request that [our chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12851/software-recommendations) heats back to life and is unfrozen by a mod?

[image: Chatroom frozen message]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have [hotted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19033/11043) it.